# Failed to parse command using ANTLR3 grammar, if command has same word which is declared as rule

Tags: grammar, antlr3

I have facing a problem while parsing some command with the parser which, I have implemented using ANLTR3. Parser fails to parse those commands which contains 'any-word' that is declared as lexer rule in the grammar.
For Example take a look following grammar:

```
show    :   
    SHOW TABLES '[' projectName? tableName']' -> ^(SHOW TABLES_ ^(PROJECT_NAME projectName)? ^(DATASET_TABLE tableName));

SHOW    :   S H O W;
```

If i try to parse command 'SHOW TABLES [sample-project:SHOW]' then parse fails for this command.But if I change the SHOW word then it works.
SHOW TABLES [sample-project:SHOW] - this works.

I don't want to get name as string which is surrounded in quotes(").
Can anyone suggest solution? I am using ANTLR3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical effect of using a reserved word as identifier. In ANTLR when you define a reserved word like your `SHOW` rule it will implicitly excluded from a identifier rule you might have defined after that keyword rule.

The solution to allow such keywords also as identifiers in rules like your `tablName` is to make that rule accept certain (or all) keywords that could be accepted in that place (and will not act as keywords then). Example:

```
tableName:
    IDENTIFIER
    | SHOW
    | <others go here>
;
```